# Extjs 4.2 attach an handler to a panel tool do not work

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Here is what I am doing:

```
Ext.define('NG.view.taxinvoice.Widget', {
    extend: 'NG.code.portal.Portlet',
    alias: 'widget.taxinvoicewidget',
    layout: 'card',

    tools: [{
        type: 'gear',
        scope: this,
        callback: 'onGearToolClick'
    }],

    items: [{
        xtype: 'taxinvoicelist'
    }, {
        html: 'taxinvoicegraph'
    }],

    onGearToolClick: function (panel) {
        alert('1111') This is not invoked!
    }
});
```

The alert statement is never fired...
can you tell me why?

**Update**

Ok the way it worked was using the accepted answer by @kevhender like this:

Ext.define('NG.view.taxinvoice.Widget', {
    extend: 'NG.code.portal.Portlet',
    alias: 'widget.taxinvoicewidget',
    layout: 'card',

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'taxinvoicelist'
}, {
    html: 'taxinvoicegraph'
}],

initComponent: function () {
    this.tools = [{
        type: 'gear',
        scope: this,
        callback: 'onGearToolClick'
    }];

    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onGearToolClick: function (panel) {
    alert('1111') Now it fires :)
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the framework supports using strings to specify the name of the callback function here, you should use the actual function.  If you want to use the member function, you'll have to define `tools` within `initComponent`:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.tools = [{
        type: 'gear',
        scope: this,
        callback: this.onGearToolClick
    }];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

You could also do it the way you have it now if you use an anonymous function:

```
Ext.define('NG.view.taxinvoice.Widget', {
    extend: 'NG.code.portal.Portlet',
    alias: 'widget.taxinvoicewidget',
    layout: 'card',

    tools: [{
        type: 'gear',
        scope: this,
        callback: function() {
            //define fn here
        }
    }],

    ...
});
```

Comment: I don t want to define the function in the callback, I want it to reside in the panel definition.

Comment: and the framework does suppot passing string as a callback see [Ext.panel.Tool](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool)

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but you should know that strings are allowed ever since version 4.2.1 and I have updated my question with what I have eventually done.

Comment: Thanks, I figured they would be heading that direction soon enough.